# PHP define() doesn't seem to be working with include()

Tags: php, class, include

I've been trying my hand at OO PHP, and currently have three files. I have a class_lib.php which, at the moment, just has a databaseServer class, an index.php file and a definitions.php file. I want to put all my sensitive database info into the definitions file. However, when I do, I get an error when trying to connect to the database: "Unkown server DB_HOST". My definitions file is:

```
<?php
define("DB_HOST","localhost");
define("DB_USER","root");
define("DB_PASS","password");
define("DB_NAME","database");
?>
```

Then I use them in the index file like so:

```
include('definitions.php');
include('class_lib.php');

$testing = new databaseServer();

$testing->connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME);
```

And the function I use in the databaseServer class is this:

```
    function connect($host,$user,$pw,$db) {
        $this->con = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pw);
        if (!$this->con) {
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
            }
        $this->selectDb($db);
        }

    function selectDb($database) {
        $this->db = mysql_select_db($database,$this->con);
        if (!$this->db) {
            echo "Could not Select database: " . mysql_error();
            }
        }
```

Any ideas why this would not work? I've also tried putting the definitions file into an include in the class_lib file, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: First, don't use require / include as a function because it isn't. 
What happens when you define those constants in the index file?

Comment: This should work fine, and I've never seen it not work. Are you 100% sure the includes are in the correct order? Can you make test outputs of the constant values in the "definitions.php" file and the index file?

Comment: @Kemo what's wrong with using `include` with braces?

Comment: @Pekka it's a language construct, not a function, so it's a good practice to use it without braces.

Comment: @Kemo but why? As long as it's consistent within a project, I don't really see the difference between using it with or without braces. Is there one? After all, `include` *can* have a return value.

Comment: @Kemo What do you mean not to use require/include as a function? Not sure I was?
@Pekka I realised my error when I tried a test output - I typoed the filename. Not in the includes, but the filename itself. Now I feel like an idiot, haha.

Comment: @Saladin no problem, happens to all of us. I'll add the comment as an answer so the question can be closed.

Comment: @Pekka of course, it's got a return value and it'll return it no mather if being used with or without braces. The consistency is important though, good point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work fine, and I've never seen it not work.

- Make 100% sure the includes are in the correct order (the defines need to be loaded first)
- Make test outputs of the constant values in the "definitions.php" file and the index file
- Make 100% sure you are calling the right files

Comment: I got here because I tried `define( "PUBLIC", __DIR__ )`. It just worked when I change _PUBLIC_ to _PUBLIC_PATH_ and I noticed that public is a **reserved word**.

Comment: checked everything but no success

Answer (score 2):

Please check if your server supports short_open_tag this value would be commented.
I just enabled it with on and it started working.

Comment: This is totally what caused it in my case. It's not in the example above but if your file starts with `<?` as opposed to `<?php` it won't be parsed as PHP in more modern versions of the language. I just hit this after a server OS update.

Answer (score 1):

call it config.php

```
if(!$link)
{

die('Failed to connect to server: ' . mysql_error());

}

$db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);
if(!$db)
{

die("Unable to select database");

}

?>
```

then include("config.php"); on your pages

Answer (score 1):

working

```
<?php
define('KLINGON_SEPARATOR', '');
?>
```

not working

```
<?php
define('KLINGON_SEPARATOR', '');
```

silly... IDEA says "redundant closing tag"

Answer (score 0):

You just need to take out the `define` functions of the destinations file and transfer it to the source file (in your case "translation.php") and ready to work!

Like this the bug with define functions on receiving string params do not happen and you will include the CONSTANTS implemented already.

I faced this trouble and found myself just this one solution.

Comment: That misses the entire point of putting the defines into a separate file.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue today and it seems to possibly be an invalid character code at the end of the file. I found this on stack [PHP define is not registering constants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7918102/php-define-is-not-registering-constants?rq=1) His solution (removing extra spaces) worked for me.

Answer (score -2):

The key in this is using the constant() function to pull the value from the defined constants:

```
echo constant("DB_USERNAME");
```