# PHP define is not registering constants

Tags: php

I'm in the prcoess of setting up my (Wordpress) solution on a new production server. I now discovere that the PHP function [`define`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php) is not working.

I have this line of code in my `functions.php`:

```
define('INCLUDE_DIR', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-content/themes/storelocator/include/');
```

Testing the following code:

```
if (!defined('INCLUDE_DIR'))
  echo ' NOT SET! ';
```

outputs `NOT SET`.

According to [this page](http://www.desilva.biz/php/constants.html), I'm using constant correct in the `include` statement.
The rest of the code in `functions.php` is running fine. I've checked.

Is this due to some PHP configuration? I'm using PHP v5.3.8

UPDATE:

`define()` is at the very top of `functions.php` file.
The `if` statement is at the very top of `some-file.php`.

I'm pretty sure `functions.php` is run before `some-file.php`.

**UPDATE**
It seems that I got this error because I had empty lines at the bottom of my PHP files. I removed the empty lines and now it seems to work :-/

Comment: Are you sure that the functions.php has been included/required BEFORE you do your defined() check? To assume you've found a PHP bug on such a simple widely-used function is pushing things a bit.

Comment: can you show where the include of functions.php is in relation to the check if defined?

Comment: @Marc B - `functions.php` is run before any other WP template file, right? So `functions.php` should run before 'some.template.php` file where I used `defined()`.

Comment: I avoid WP's internals like the plague, so no idea. Easy enough to verify though - just have functions.php log something or output something and see if you get that before an equivalent log/output call in your main function occurs.

Comment: @Patrick - `functions.php` is automatically run by Wordpress before any other template files are loaded.

Comment: @Mar B - I just did. `echo 'ONE -'` in funtions.php and `echo ' TWO -'` in the other file. And it outputed `ONE - TWO -`

Comment: I've been scratching my head at this one but that proposed solution worked for me. I guess I had an invalid character code. I tried pressing control z to see If I could reproduce but nothing. I'll keep scratching my head here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must call the `define()` function *before* you check to see if the constant has been `defined()`. If you are doing so (try putting your `define` call immediately above your `defined` call) then I can see no reason why this wouldn't work.

Comment: Can you confirm you've not put the define call inside a function accidentally?

Comment: All constants for my site is put in functions.php and no where else. I'm sure of that. It works fine on my local server and my previous test server, just not on this new server.

Comment: In which case: are you absolutely positive you've edited the correct copy of the correct file? Try putting a die() statement just after the define line and seeing if the script does exit.

Comment: As I said to Marc, I tried echo at the top of both files to see what came first. It came in the right order. It seems that it might just have been empty line at the bottom of the PHP file that caused this error. My previous server var CentOS, but now I'm using Ubuntu. But I'm not sure if this has anything to do with this.

Comment: Check my comment above. Looks like empty lines at the bottom of the PHP file vas the cultrip. And since you're the only one with an answer, I will grant you the "solved" points :)

Answer (score 1):

I just had the exact same problem and solved it by removing underscores from the constant's name. Hopefully this helps.