# PHP include doesn't work

Tags: php

I'm not sure how simple is this to solve, but I assume I'm doing something wrong. I'm new to PHP, so bear with me, please.

When I started learning PHP, I always placed all my project files into the same folder along with `index.php` and thus included everything like this:

```
<?php
include('./translation.php');
?>
```

Later on in the process of learning as I gained experience and my skill increased, I had to start using folders and place my files into sub folders. I ended up successfully including my files with the following:

```
<?php
include('../translation.php');
?>
```

My trouble-free coding took an unexpected turn when I decided to start using sub-sub folders. After placing all the files even deeper into the file structure I was shocked to find out that I cannot include them anymore, using:

```
<?php
include('.../translation.php');
?>
```

Now I'm lost. What did I do wrong? Am I to understand that I cannot include files deeper than 2 directories in the project? Should I start using a different file system?

Comment: In most filesystems, `..` refers to the parent directory of the current one, so you can chain together as many as you need via `../../../../` etc, with a `/` between to delineate directories.  The single dot `.` refers to the current directory, so `./././././` still refers to the same (current) directory.

Comment: As you create larger projects it becomes helpful to define a value like `define('SITE_ROOT', dirname(__FILE__));` at the top level, and then include others as with `include(SITE_ROOT . "/../translation.php");`

Comment: I already anshered some trouble at this post, maybe can help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510909/php-define-doesnt-seem-to-be-working-with-include

Answer (score 10):

You got the concept incorrect.

- `.` represents current directory
- `..` represents parent directory

These are the way a file system keeps in track of the file and browse depth.

But you cannot use `...` to change the directory. As you go deeper, you have to use

For example:

```
include('../../translation.php');
```

includes the files, two level outside of current directory. Which is probably what you were trying to do.

Comment: +1 but i would change "previous" to "parent". cause ".." is not the same a pressing the "back" button.

Answer (score 4):

The include should be:

```
<?php
include('../../translation.php');
?>
```

Each level 'up' needs its own `../`.

For example, if you had the following directories:

```
a
   a1
      filex.php
   a2
b
   b1
      filey.php
```

If in filex.php, you wanted to include filey.php, you would do the following:

```
<?php
include('../../b/b1/filey.php');
?>
```

*Up/out twice, down/ib twice*

Basically, any time you want to go 'down' a level / into a folder, you give the name of the folder followed by a forward slash. But to go 'up' or out of the current folder (to the parent folder of the current folder) you give `..` followed by the forward slash

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go deeper (subfolder of subfolder), just use `../../`

```
include("../../translation.php");
```

However, if your project is middle size or big size, I'd rather suggest you to define absolute path. In your index.php or whatever your included file is, define something like `SITE_ROOT` or `INCLUDES_ROOT`.

```
define("SITE_ROOT", dirname(__FILE__));
```

and then just use it on demand.

```
include(SITE_ROOT."/../../translation.php");
```

which is pretty useful in case you are including files from different folders

That said, imagine you have this folder structure

- ROOT

  - includes/

    - boot.php
  - translations

    - en.php
  - ajax/

    - ajax2/

      - ajaxfile.php
  - index.php

---

CASE1:  (fails)

index.php includes

```
<?php
include("includes/boot.php");
```

ajax/ajax2/ajaxfile.php includes

```
<?php
include("../../includes/boot.php");
```

includes/boot.php includes

```
<?php 
include("translations/en.php"); // from index.php it works but from ajax/ajax2/ajaxfile.php it searches for wrong file
```

CASE2: (passes)

ajax/ajax2/ajaxfile.php and index.php has the same content as the CASE1

includes/boot.php includes

```
<?php
define("INCLUDES_ROOT", dirname(__FILE__));
include(INCLUDES_ROOT."/../translations/en.php");
```

which passes, because `INCLUDES_ROOT` makes sure that the whole include point to the correct directory!

Answer (score -1):

Let's assume this tree of folders.

```
-> site
      -> public_html (Inside the site folder)
            ->  index.php (Inside the public_html folder)
      -> translation.php (Inside the site folder)
```

in your index.php you just have to use `include "../translation.php";`

if the translation.php is in the same folder as the site folder, you use `include "../../translation.php";`

if your translation.php is in the same folder as the index.php though, 
you just have to include like this: `include "translation.php";`